# Efficient way to calculate date-by-date rolling aggregation of the last 30 days

Tags: r, loops, optimization, aggregate

My codes executes just fine, however it takes an enourmous amount of time to finalize. Would like some help to optimize the code, if possible, a way to execute a rolling aggregation on multiple columns.

I've been tring a few other ways by creating a function and vectorizing my dataframe with library(data.table), but no success in doing so, i actually get half of what i should get and I can only do with one column at a time.

```
#   Creating functions
fun <- function(x, date, thresh) {
    D <- as.matrix(dist(date)) #distance matrix between dates
    D <- D <= thresh
    D[lower.tri(D)] <- FALSE #don't sum to future
    R <- D * x #FALSE is treated as 0
    colMeans(R, na.rm = TRUE)
}

setDT(df_2)
df_2[, invoiceDate := as.Date(invoiceDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]
setkey(df_2, cod_unb, cod_pdv, invoiceDate)

df_2[, volume_total_diario_RT30 := fun(volume_total_diario, invoiceDate, 30), by = list(cod_unb, cod_pdv)]
```

This is my current code that works fine, but takes too much time (Over 8h to process 30 days)

```
years <- c(2017:2019)
months <- c(1:12)
days <- c(1:31)

df_final <- df_n[1,c('cod_unb','cod_pdv','cpf_cnpj','idade_pdv_meses','status_telefone','col1','col2','col3','year','month','day')] #eliminating first line

for (i in years) {
    for (j in months) {
        for (k in days) {
            if (j == 1){
                df_temp <- df_n[(df_n$years == i & df_n$months == j & df_n$days <= k) | (df_n$years == (i-1) & df_n$months == 12 & df_n$days >= k),]    
            }                                    
            if (j != 1){                                   
                df_temp <- df_n[(df_n$years == i & df_n$months == j & df_n$days <= k) | (df_n$years == i & df_n$months == (j - 1) & df_n$days >= k),] 
            }

            #Agreggate.
            if(nrow(df_temp) >= 1){
df_temp <- aggregate(df_temp[, c('col1','col2','col3')], by = list(df_temp$cod_unb,df_temp$cod_pdv,df_temp$cpf_cnpj,df_temp$idade_pdv_meses,df_temp$status_telefone), FUN = mean)

names(df_temp)[names(df_temp) == "Group.1"] <- "cod_unb"
names(df_temp)[names(df_temp) == "Group.2"] <- "cod_pdv"
names(df_temp)[names(df_temp) == "Group.3"] <- "cpf_cnpj"
names(df_temp)[names(df_temp) == "Group.4"] <- "idade_pdv_meses"
names(df_temp)[names(df_temp) == "Group.5"] <- "status_telefone"

        df_temp$years <- i         
        df_temp$months <- j
        df_temp$days <- k        
        df_final <- rbind(df_final,df_temp)
            }                                
        }                       
    }           
}

df_final <- df_final[-1,]
```

Output should be column `R30`

```
cod_unb;cod_pdv;Years;Months;Days;date;volume_total_diario;R30
111;1005;2018;11;3;03/11/2018;0.48;
111;1005;2018;11;9;09/11/2018;0.79035;
111;1005;2018;11;16;16/11/2018;1.32105;
111;1005;2018;11;24;24/11/2018;0.6414;
111;1005;2018;11;30;30/11/2018;0.6;
111;1005;2018;12;7;07/12/2018;1.79175;1.02891
111;1005;2018;12;15;15/12/2018;1.4421;1.15926
111;1005;2018;12;21;21/12/2018;0.48;0.99105
111;1005;2018;12;28;28/12/2018;0.5535;0.97347
111;1005;2019;1;4;04/01/2019;0.36;0.92547
```

Comment: You're aggregating every day 30 times. You could aggregate to a day and then compute the rolling average within those daily aggregates.

Comment: I don't have a registry every single day for the same key. My client usually buys once or twice a week. I'm trying to aggregate all purchases by cliente in a date range of d-30 for each day.

Comment: Then it probably makes the most sense to instead add to the sum for all of d to d+30 based on each purchase. The call to aggregate is slow, you need to replace it with some code that does just what you need from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP has requested to aggregate values over a rolling period of 30 days and to append these aggregates to the original data.

This can be solved efficiently by *aggregating in a non-equi join*.

Here is an example for one variable using sample data provided by the OP:

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table, coerce character date to class IDate
setDT(df_n)[, date := as.IDate(date, "%d/%m/%Y")]
# intermediate result for demonstration:
df_n[.(upper = date, lower = date - 30), on = .(date <= upper, date >= lower), 
     mean(volume_total_diario), by = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>           date       date       V1
>  1: 2018-11-03 2018-10-04 0.480000
>  2: 2018-11-09 2018-10-10 0.635175
>  3: 2018-11-16 2018-10-17 0.863800
>  4: 2018-11-24 2018-10-25 0.808200
>  5: 2018-11-30 2018-10-31 0.766560
>  6: 2018-12-07 2018-11-07 1.028910
>  7: 2018-12-15 2018-11-15 1.159260
>  8: 2018-12-21 2018-11-21 0.991050
>  9: 2018-12-28 2018-11-28 0.973470
> 10: 2019-01-04 2018-12-05 0.925470
> ```

The intermediate result shows the upper and lower limits of the date range included in the aggregation and the aggragated values for the respective periods. This can be used to add a new column to `df_n`:

```
# update df_n by appending new column
setDT(df_n)[, R30_new := df_n[.(upper = date, lower = date - 30), on = .(date <= upper, date >= lower), 
                       mean(volume_total_diario), by = .EACHI]$V1]
df_n
```

> ```
>     cod_unb cod_pdv Years Months Days       date volume_total_diario     R30  R30_new
>  1:     111    1005  2018     11    3 2018-11-03             0.48000      NA 0.480000
>  2:     111    1005  2018     11    9 2018-11-09             0.79035      NA 0.635175
>  3:     111    1005  2018     11   16 2018-11-16             1.32105      NA 0.863800
>  4:     111    1005  2018     11   24 2018-11-24             0.64140      NA 0.808200
>  5:     111    1005  2018     11   30 2018-11-30             0.60000      NA 0.766560
>  6:     111    1005  2018     12    7 2018-12-07             1.79175 1.02891 1.028910
>  7:     111    1005  2018     12   15 2018-12-15             1.44210 1.15926 1.159260
>  8:     111    1005  2018     12   21 2018-12-21             0.48000 0.99105 0.991050
>  9:     111    1005  2018     12   28 2018-12-28             0.55350 0.97347 0.973470
> 10:     111    1005  2019      1    4 2019-01-04             0.36000 0.92547 0.925470
> ```

The values of `R30` and `R30_new` are identical; `R30_new` contains also results for the first 5 rows.

#### Caveat

Additional grouping variables have been ignored for the sake of clarity but can be included easily. Also, the solution can be extended to aggregate multiple value columns.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df_n <- fread("
cod_unb;cod_pdv;Years;Months;Days;date;volume_total_diario;R30
111;1005;2018;11;3;03/11/2018;0.48;
111;1005;2018;11;9;09/11/2018;0.79035;
111;1005;2018;11;16;16/11/2018;1.32105;
111;1005;2018;11;24;24/11/2018;0.6414;
111;1005;2018;11;30;30/11/2018;0.6;
111;1005;2018;12;7;07/12/2018;1.79175;1.02891
111;1005;2018;12;15;15/12/2018;1.4421;1.15926
111;1005;2018;12;21;21/12/2018;0.48;0.99105
111;1005;2018;12;28;28/12/2018;0.5535;0.97347
111;1005;2019;1;4;04/01/2019;0.36;0.92547
")
```

#### EDIT: Aggregating multiple variables

As the OP has  asked for *a way to execute a rolling aggregation on multiple columns* here is an example.

First, we need to create an additional value var in OP's sample dataset:

```
df_n <- fread("
cod_unb;cod_pdv;Years;Months;Days;date;volume_total_diario;R30
111;1005;2018;11;3;03/11/2018;0.48;
111;1005;2018;11;9;09/11/2018;0.79035;
111;1005;2018;11;16;16/11/2018;1.32105;
111;1005;2018;11;24;24/11/2018;0.6414;
111;1005;2018;11;30;30/11/2018;0.6;
111;1005;2018;12;7;07/12/2018;1.79175;1.02891
111;1005;2018;12;15;15/12/2018;1.4421;1.15926
111;1005;2018;12;21;21/12/2018;0.48;0.99105
111;1005;2018;12;28;28/12/2018;0.5535;0.97347
111;1005;2019;1;4;04/01/2019;0.36;0.92547
")[
  , date := as.IDate(date, "%d/%m/%Y")][, var2 := .I][]
df_n
```

> ```
>    cod_unb cod_pdv Years Months Days       date volume_total_diario     R30 var2
>  1:     111    1005  2018     11    3 2018-11-03             0.48000      NA    1
>  2:     111    1005  2018     11    9 2018-11-09             0.79035      NA    2
>  3:     111    1005  2018     11   16 2018-11-16             1.32105      NA    3
>  4:     111    1005  2018     11   24 2018-11-24             0.64140      NA    4
>  5:     111    1005  2018     11   30 2018-11-30             0.60000      NA    5
>  6:     111    1005  2018     12    7 2018-12-07             1.79175 1.02891    6
>  7:     111    1005  2018     12   15 2018-12-15             1.44210 1.15926    7
>  8:     111    1005  2018     12   21 2018-12-21             0.48000 0.99105    8
>  9:     111    1005  2018     12   28 2018-12-28             0.55350 0.97347    9
> 10:     111    1005  2019      1    4 2019-01-04             0.36000 0.92547   10
> ```

So, a column `var2` has been added (which simply contains the row number).

This is the code to aggregate multiple column using the same aggregation function:

```
cols <- c("volume_total_diario", "var2")
setDT(df_n)[, paste0("mean_", cols) := 
       df_n[.(upper = date, lower = date - 30), 
            on = .(date <= upper, date >= lower), 
            lapply(.SD, mean), 
            .SDcols = cols, by = .EACHI][
              , .SD, .SDcols = cols]][]
df_n
```

> ```
>     cod_unb cod_pdv Years Months Days       date volume_total_diario     R30 var2 mean_volume_total_diario mean_var2
>  1:     111    1005  2018     11    3 2018-11-03             0.48000      NA    1                 0.480000       1.0
>  2:     111    1005  2018     11    9 2018-11-09             0.79035      NA    2                 0.635175       1.5
>  3:     111    1005  2018     11   16 2018-11-16             1.32105      NA    3                 0.863800       2.0
>  4:     111    1005  2018     11   24 2018-11-24             0.64140      NA    4                 0.808200       2.5
>  5:     111    1005  2018     11   30 2018-11-30             0.60000      NA    5                 0.766560       3.0
>  6:     111    1005  2018     12    7 2018-12-07             1.79175 1.02891    6                 1.028910       4.0
>  7:     111    1005  2018     12   15 2018-12-15             1.44210 1.15926    7                 1.159260       5.0
>  8:     111    1005  2018     12   21 2018-12-21             0.48000 0.99105    8                 0.991050       6.0
>  9:     111    1005  2018     12   28 2018-12-28             0.55350 0.97347    9                 0.973470       7.0
> 10:     111    1005  2019      1    4 2019-01-04             0.36000 0.92547   10                 0.925470       8.0
> ```

Note that the new columns have been named programmtically.

Comment: i'm getting an error: `unused argument (on = .(date <= upper, date >= lower))`

Comment: One possible reason: `df_n` is not of class data.table. Check with `class()` or `str()`.

Comment: when I run `setDT(df_n)` it should be set as class data.table, no?

Comment: I ran the exact same code with the correct adjustments, still getting the error

Comment: Yes `setDT(df_n)` should set the class of `df_n` to data.table. Are there any other data frames involved?

Comment: Not in this step, i first execute this calc and then merge to another data frame, but it crashes in this step:
`setDT(df_n)[, paste0("mean_", cols) := 
       df_n[.(upper = date, lower = date - 30), 
            on = .(date <= upper, date >= lower), 
            lapply(.SD, mean), 
            .SDcols = cols, by = .EACHI][
              , .SD, .SDcols = cols]][]`

Comment: my date column is returning int numbers `date;
17866;
17898;
17899;
17868;` is this supposed to happen when i run the `IDate` ?

Comment: Please, can you post `str(df_n)` to see what `df_n` looks like before it stops with the "unused argument" error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187208/discussion-between-uwe-and-lucas-mascia).